# Native Dynamic sql,Execute immediate

Tags: oracle, plsql

```
EXECUTE immediate 'SELECT COUNT(*) INTO var_total_rows FROM '||v_table_name   || ' where  ENQUIRY_NO = :enq_no' 
--INTO var_total_rows USING enq_no;
```

this is   giving error of missing keyword . I am trying to  count the number of rows  fetched  after passing the enquiry number   for each table . approx 68 tables are  in the output

thanks

Comment: Try `EXECUTE immediate 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM '||v_table_name   || ' where  ENQUIRY_NO = :enq_no' INTO var_total_rows USING enq_no`

Comment: BTW. Be sure that `v_table_name` is validated, to avoid SQL Injection risk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this way:

```
DECLARE
   v_table_name     VARCHAR2 (20) := 'emp';
   enq_no           NUMBER := 5;
   var_total_rows   NUMBER;
BEGIN
   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
      'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM  ' || v_table_name || ' where  EMPNO = :enq_no'
      INTO var_total_rows
      USING enq_no;

   DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (var_total_rows);
END;
```

Edit:
This works for me. I just replaced `ENQUIRY_NO` with `EMPLOYEE_ID` since my schema doesnot have that table. Please make sure to assign value to variable `enq_no`

```
declare
var_total_rows number;
enq_no number:=1;
BEGIN
   FOR c1 IN (SELECT DISTINCT table_name
                FROM user_tab_columns
               WHERE column_name = 'EMPLOYEE_ID' ) --'ENQUIRY_NO')
   LOOP
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (' ');
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('Table = ' || c1.table_name);
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('=========================');

      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
            'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM '
         || c1.table_name
         || ' where EMPLOYEE_ID = :enq_no'
         INTO var_total_rows
         USING enq_no;

      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('total count:' || var_total_rows);
   END LOOP;
END;
```

Output:

```
Table = EMPLOYEE
=========================
total count:1
Table = BONUSES
=========================
total count:1
Table = BONUSESS
=========================
total count:0
```

Comment: The  code looks correct but the error is  just not going . its giving invalid number error  .the reason as I see could be due to .. that I am passing enquiry number  which is varchar2 in some tables and number in some other tables . the program  checks  and displays the  table name  having enquiry number as one column and then has to count the number of rows  based on  that enquiry number .

Comment: Not sure how your table data is bt what i have posted is working example whihc you can follow and make necesary changes

Comment: for c1 in
  ( SELECT DISTINCT table_name    FROM user_tab_columns     WHERE column_name='ENQUIRY_NO')
  loop    
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(' ');
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Table = ' || c1.table_name );
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('=========================');
   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
      'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM  ' || c1.table_name || ' where ENQUIRY_NO = :enq_no'
      INTO var_total_rows
      USING enq_no;

   
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('total count:'||var_total_rows);
  END LOOP;

Comment: this code is giving invalid number error  consistently ..even if i use to_char  or chr ..the error doesnt go

Comment: yes its working now .I went crazy looking into the error . the  enquity_number  column   declaring as number is correcting the code